# Начало отсчета на canvas в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

По идее верхний левый угол точка 0,0.
Но код

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
 
canvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, bg='white')
canvas.pack()
 
canvas.create_line(0, 0, 5, 5, fill='red')
 
root.mainloop()
```

рисует линию из 3-х точек, а должен из 5: 0,0; 1,1, 2,2, 3,3, 4,4.

Так же линия `canvas.create_line(1, 1, 50, 1, fill='red')` не будет видна, а
линия `canvas.create_line(2, 2, 50, 2, fill='red')` будет.

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Под Windows Canvas создается с серой границей в два пикселя, ее будет видно, если фон окна сделать белым:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ее можно убрать, если при создании Canvas указать параметр `highlightthickness=0`:

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, bg='white', highlightthickness=0)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. ответ от [T.P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441087) на вопрос [How do I remove the light grey border around my Canvas widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4311134/4752653)